# Running yum update and I get this error

Tags: centos, yum

**Getting this error below when I try to run yum update, I am guessing it has something to do with atrpms repo but I am not sure how to fix it**

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                            |  14 kB     00:00
 * base: centos.chi.host-engine.com
 * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
 * extras: mirror.fusioncloud.co
 * updates: bay.uchicago.edu
http://dl.atrpms.net/el6-x86_64/atrpms/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: atrpms. Please verify its path and try again
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fix. Try using

`sed -i "s/mirrorlist=https/mirrorlist=http/" /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`

Comment: Hallelujah! Thank you.